# How do I close all Socket objects that have been spawned by a ServerSocket?

Tags: java, sockets

For a very basic webserver, I have some ServerSocket code that looks roughly like that (in the `run()` method of a thread), that listens on a specified port and accepts clients:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
while (true) {
    try {
        Socket client = server.accept();
        ClientThread clientThread = new ClientThread(client);
        clientThread.start();
    } catch(Exception e)
    {}
}
```

Now, this part works, I can access the webserver from my browser and all, and I can close the server with `server.close()` whenever I want to from the caller.
However, when I do that, if there are spawned client sockets with some kind of keep-alive connection (because I already accessed a page), those Socket objects still exist, and continue to answer requests, which I don’t want (the server should stop answering all requests when it is stopped, and cut every established connection).

How can I close all of those spawned client sockets?
My guess is that I could manually keep a reference to every "child" Socket, in an array, then when the server is closed, loop through that array to manually close every socket object that has not yet been closed by the client, but this does not look very optimal to me (nor foolproof).

Is there a simpler, more robust way to do that?

Comment: Not an array but rather an ArrayList, and yes, this is probably the best way to solve this.

Comment: But rather than keep every "socket" reference in a collection, keep every ClientThread in a collection and give it a `public void close()` method that closes its own Socket if it is not null and is running.

Comment: Also, avoid ignoring exceptions as you're doing: `catch(Exception e)
    {}`

Comment: Yes, I am planning to do that. Thank you for your help.